# Should I use critical section or syncronize/queue to modify class data members?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, critical-section, thread-synchronization, tthread

Let's say `TForm1` class (default main window) contains data member `int x;`. If I create additional threads from `TThread` descendant should I use critical section object or *Synchronize/Queue* methods to modify value of `x` inside thread's *Execute* method?

I know that *Synchronize/Queue* are used when thread makes changes to VCL components. But, does that also applies here just because `x` is declared inside VCL's `TForm1` or I can simply use critical section object instead?

Comment: It depends. Another option are atomic increment and friends. It all depends on how the variable is used. We can't advise you what to do without that detail.

Comment: Like David says, it depends on your use case. Anyway, a Critical Section is a lightweight solution comparing to using Synchronize/Queue